# ASP.NET MVC add/remove IIS app name/alias from URL dynamically

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis, visual-studio-2012

Because of the IIS 6.1 settings, every app that's being deployed has an alias and that has an impact on the URL. In Visual Studio's development server, the URL looks like this:

> http://localhost:27019/controller/action

But after being deployed to IIS:

> http://servername/appname/controller/action

as you can see there is an `appname` added to the URL. All the Ajax calls become incorrect after deployment. I have to create an `isIIS` variable and manually assign a value to it in order to make it work:

```
var isIIS = true; // set to false if runs locally;    
window.appAlias = (isIIS) ? '/'+window.location.href.split('/')[3] : '';
```

And in my Ajax call:

```
$.post( window.appAlias  + webUrl, {} , callback );
```

same thing with GET calls, I have to prepend the `window.appAlias`. Is there a way to dynamically detect whether the server is IIS or Visual Studio Development Server? I understand the `@Uri.Content("~/controller/action")` but I am not writing my JavaScript on the Razor view.

I am using Visual Studio 2012, target framework .NET 4.5, MVC 4 and jQuery 1.9.2 for development. The IIS application pool has .NET 4.0.

---

**Edit**
Here is my temporary solution: to add global values in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
Object.assign({
  action1: '@Url.Content("~/controller/action1")',
  action2: '@Url.Content("~/controller/action2")'
}, window);
```

Comment: Always use `@Url.Action()` to correctly generate your urls.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but I am separating my JavaScript files to View files

Comment: There are multile ways to handle that. Assign a global variable in your main view (e.g. `var url = '@Url.Action(...)'`). Assign it to a `data-url` attribute in the element that your handling. Have an `init()` function in the external file that you can pass it to from the main view etc

Comment: I am interested in the `init()` function. Can you talk about it please?

Comment: You might just have a `function init(url)` method in the external script which sets the value of a variable that script that can be used in your ajax calls, and then in the main view initialize it by calling that method - `myScript.init('@Url.Action(...)');`